# How to generate string matches regular expression in .NET

Tags: .net, regex

Can you tell me please how to generate string that matches particular regular expression using .NET 4?

Thanks!

Comment: Curious - why do you need it?

Comment: Generate testing data. For example, emails or nanPhones by regexp.

Comment: [Regular Expression Random Data Generator](https://code.google.com/p/rxrdg/), written in C#.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

there are not library at the moment that allow to generate matching string against a RegEx

the only one I know is implemented in Java (http://code.google.com/p/xeger/)

you can write your own .dll to achieve that

http://www.kodefuguru.com/post/2010/05/03/Generate-Matches-for-Regular-Expressions-Using-Rex.aspx

http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/projects/rex/